# Aws Elastic BeanStalk Multi Docker Container LoadBalancing Problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am learning aws and having problem deploying my docker-compose(with two service) to elastic bean stalk. When I try to crate multi docker container on user interface with single instance options, there will be no loadbalancer and I can reach my containers by adding inbound rule in securiy group for elastic bean stalk environment.

But when I try to create env over eb cli on my console, system asks me which type of loadbalancer I need , I select application load balancer, and environment is created with load balancer.

When I go to environment url, it dipslays 502 Bad Gateway.
And sometimes timeout exception..

So I believe, I am missing a good point because I also did not understand how aws will route my request over my env url to my docker containers, how can it know which port it should redirect the request from port 80.

I really dig a lot of resource and follow some youtube and udemy courses but couldn't find the solution.

Thank you in advance,

this is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'todos'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'todos-user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'dummytodos'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'dummypassword'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
  todo-service:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: ozenoglu/multitodoarch
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

Comment: Are you using a framework? If so, what language? For example, I run Django projects. nginx listens on port 80 and uses proxy_pass to an upstream named "django_app" with a `server web:8000;` line. Is there a port your app typically runs on?

Comment: Hi @Jarad , I am trying to run spring boot apps on aws. I can run single instance with Java Envrionment or Tomcat Environment. But I want to achieve is a general way to run any docker. So Docker can have different programs in it and can run on different port so my need is something general way to launch multi docker containers on aws.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the port, or inbound rules on security groups. 1. I would try allowing "Anywhere" on your security groups for http and https. 2. It seems boot spring default port is 8080, so make sure you're mapping ports correctly like 80:8080. You need to confirm what port your application is running on I think.